# Difference between steady state intensity and saturation intensity in laser

Tags: laser, intensity

Can someone explain the difference between steady state intensity and saturation intensity in lasers? And difference between gain at threshold and gain at steady state, why are these two gain equal?

Answer (score 0):

Saturation takes place before than steady state.   At saturation intensity exponential grows of gain convert to linear. When gain and loss become equal then steady state take place.

Comment: This isn't my field, but how does "exponential grows of gain convert to linear" work?

Comment: dI/I=gdz
dI/dz=gI=I(g0/(1+I/Isat)
for I>>Isat
dI/dz=g0Isat
I=I0+g0Isat

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post. While editing to add this in, you may want to consider adding more details, as it is unclear how this answers the post.

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se], Amir! If you're having trouble accessing one of the accounts you've just made, please use the [contact form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact).